# What should I modify such that browser gives me the option to save the returned file?

Tags: java, spring

```
@GetMapping(value = "/draftReport", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public void generateDraftResport(@RequestParam("schoolID") String schoolID, HttpServletResponse response) {
     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "draft_export.xlsx");
     try {
        InputStream is = exportHandler.draftReport(schoolID);
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
        System.out.println("Successfully written");
    }

    catch (IOException ex) {
          log.info("Error writing file to output stream. " + ex);
          System.out.println("Error while writing file");
    }
}
```

The draftReport method returns an InputStream containing the XSSFWorkbook data. On invoking my Api '/draftReport', I want that file to be available to the browser to save. What am I missing, if at all? I get all the success logs, but no download popup.

Comment: 1. Your method doesn't actually produce JSON, so remove that produeces attribute. 2. How do you send a request to your server?

Comment: `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`?

Comment: @JBNizet I am making an ajax call using jquery to invoke '/draftReport'. I also get success for the ajax call (in console)

Comment: @JoopEggen Should I be using something different? I think this is what we use for forced download of a file?

Comment: Then since you're programmatically sending the request, you're responsible to programmatically handle the response If you want the browser to deal with the download, then the browser should send the request, without AJAX. Use window.location to tell the user to navigate to the URL of your resource, and it will download the file.

Comment: How does a browser send request without ajax? Also, This is my ajax : - $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'/draftReport',
    data: 'schoolID='+schoolId,
    xhrFields:{
     withCredentials:true
    },
    success:function(response){
     console.log("Report created successfully");
    },
    error:function(response){
     console.log("Failed to create report");
    }
   }) What change do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest to use window.location to tell the user to navigate to the URL of your resource, and it will download the file.

Comment: I meant "tell the browser", not "tell the user".

Comment: Thanks bro...you helped me with something I was stuck with for 2 and a half days.